# How to hook "stash save" to require a custom stash message?

Tags: git, githooks, git-stash

Often when doing `git stash` I forget to supply a custom message.  How would I go about making a hook which would reject stash creation unless there was a custom message?

Comment: create an alias for `git stash save` and use that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the current version of git (1.8.3), it is not possible to alias existing git commands or override them by supplying a git-command script (such as git-stash) in your path.

You are left with making do with a shell function, but this is arguably also the most appropriate thing to do anyway. For instance, you could add something along these lines to your `.bashrc`:

```
function git() {
    if [[ $1 == stash ]] && [[ $2 == save ]]; then
        SAVED_ARGS=("$@")
        shift; shift;
        while test $# != 0; do
            case "$1" in
            --) shift; break;;
            -*) ;;
            esac
            shift;
        done
        [[ -z "$*" ]] && { echo "Error - empty stash message!"; return 1; }
        command git "${SAVED_ARGS[@]}"
    else
        command git "$@"
    fi
}
```

This will intercept only an empty `git stash save`, and forward everything else to git as-is. Optional arguments to git stash save will be passed on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git stash save "<your_message>"`

Comment: I know that.  I sometimes forget to do that, so I want to make git reject attempts to save a stash without the message.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using normal git checkins instead of stash?

```
$ git checkout my_work_branch
$ $EDITOR file.c
# At this point you are in the middle of some new change but then want
# temporarily save to do another change first

$ git co -b stash
$ git add file.c
$ git commit -m "custom stash message"
$ git checkout my_work_branch
$ $EDITOR file.c
$ git add file.c
$ git commit -m "Some other fix"

$ git rebase --onto my_work_branch stash^ stash
$ git reset HEAD^
$ git checkout my_work_branch
$ git branch -D stash
```

Yes, I get that this is more commands to write, but this way you have full control of everything and there is no way this can fail. I only briefly used git stash many years ago when starting to learn git, but to me it was too fragile and recovering from a failing `git stash pop` was either not possible or very difficult. Maybe git stash has improved since then, but in any case I do not like the way stash messes up the displayed version tree in gitk, so I prefer the way described above.

Comment: The point of [git stash](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing) is "... [when] you don’t want to do a commit of half-done work just so you can get back to this point later." I agree though that `pop` is messy, I always use `git stash apply`. Additionally, `git stash` already operates via commits, it just hides this fact from you.